# Why is the correct answer 'to have been cleaned'?

Tags: passive-voice, past-simple, infinitives, to-infinitive

I'm doing my grammar practice of infinitive verbs.

> The room is said ( ) last week.
>
> A. to clean
>
> B. to be cleaned
>
> C. to have cleaned
>
> D. to have been cleaned √

According to my intuition of English language, it seems the correct one is B, but why not? I think on this occasion just using the past-simple is okay.

Comment: But "be cleaned" isn't the simple past.  The simple past would be "was cleaned".

Comment: On dit que la pièce a été nettoyé (to have been cleaned) la semaine dernière.

Answer (score 1):

As a non-native speaker myself, my intuition of English language told me that the correct answer was D. In my opinion, many times it is very difficult for most people to explain why something is or is not correct in terms of grammar. They just know it, because they have come across similar constructions numerous times in the past and it's been registered in their subconcious mind. Take a look at the following sentences:

It is said the room has been cleaned = The room is said to have been cleaned.

And compare it with:

I want the room to be cleaned.
I wanted the room to be cleaned.

Whenever I see something that I don't understand in English, instead of trying to understand why it is or is not correct, I simply accept it and try to make similar sentences of my own until the strcuture registers in my subconcious mind, just like a native speaker. Now that you know D is correct, you can make sentences such as:

The lions are said to have been killed.
The car is said to have been fixed.
The employee is said to have been fired.
The bear is said to have been hunted.

This is the best way to learn a language without worrying about grammatical rules. All you have to do is have a sentence pattern in your mind and then apply it to similar cases.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Right, the past passive is to have been cleaned. Exactly. Also, +1 for your attitude. Instead of learning this or that point and accepting it, people fight it. One never learns that way...:)

Answer (score 0):

"Past simple" does not enter into it, because these are all infinitive clauses, and don't have a tense.

Nevertheless, even with non-finite verb forms (infinitives, participles), English has the option of moving them into the relative past by using *have X-en* (in this case *to have been cleaned*).

In this case, because the main verb, *is*, is non-past, you need to put the infinitive in the past for consistency with the temporal expression *last week*.

If the main verb were past, then I think you could get away without:

> This room was said to be cleaned last week.

though the *have* would still be possible, and some would prefer it for clarity:

> This room was said to have been cleaned last week.

(As is often the case with practice sentences, I can't imagine anybody actually saying this. Only academic writers, and sometimes journalists, use "X is said to be *verb*-ed".)

Answer (score 0):

You need "have been cleaned" because the intended meaning is that, at the time that it was said, the room had already been cleaned.

Option a, "to clean," would mean that the room itself is constantly cleaning [something unspecified]. It also doesn't work with "last week", because it is present continuous.

Option b, "to be cleaned," would mean that the room is in a state of cleanliness currently ("cleaned" as an adjetive), which doesn't make sense with "last week".

Option c, "to have cleaned," would mean that the room had cleaned [something unspecified] last week. Grammatically, it works, except that it makes no sense because rooms can't clean.

Option 4, "to have been cleaned," means that it is said that last week, the room had been cleaned. This is what you want.